# Place additional info in HTML table header <th>

Tags: html

I have an HTML table that looks like this:

[image: HTML table]

I want to add additional information into the BoM, CIT, and SIT `<th>` cells. This info will list the number of successes, failures, and incompletes. Essentially, I would like the title to stay bold and bigger, and then the extra info will be smaller and to the right. It will be three lines.

I am terrible at design… Can someone give me some design guidance and HTML that will accommodate my needs and look pretty good?

Comment: Please read about [what topics you should ask about on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - this is subjective, too broad and generally not "solveable".

Answer (score 1):

You can store the extra info using HTML5's [custom attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) tags:

```
<th>
    <td data-attribute1="something" data-attribute2="someotherthing">Component</td>
    <td>BoM</td>
    <!-- etc. -->
</th>
```

Comment: The extra info needs to show up to the right of the header. These tags won't show up, will they?

Comment: Use Javascript to add them in. Can you at least provide a mockup of what you want?